# choosing different css classes for unique variable

Tags: php, ajax, woocommerce

I have 2 different styles for a variable which is available in 2 different position of page:

```
/* Header Bar Count*/
.sticky-count {
    font-size: 1em;
}

/* Footer Bar Count*/
.sticky-count-footer {
    font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

And I have this code to update  *$cart_count* variable via Ajax event:

```
// Woocommerce Ajax Count

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'refresh_cart_count', 50, 1 );
function refresh_cart_count( $fragments ){
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <span class="e434-21 x-bar-content-area sticky-count" id="cart-count"><?php
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    echo sprintf ( _n( '%d', '%d', $cart_count ), $cart_count );
    ?></span>
    <?php
     $fragments['.sticky-count, .sticky-count-footer'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;
}
```

Now every time that `$cart_count` changes, both items in header and footer will update but `.sticky-count-footer` style will be similar to `.sticky-count`! How can I update value of `.sticky-count-footer` with its own CSS properties?

Comment: Add `AJAX` to your tags in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround your code returned by the method with a container, if not already done and give them the class `header` and `footer`. In your response only use `.sticky-count` as class. Update your stylesheet and use `.header .sticky-count` and `.footer .sticky-count` as selectors.